# Make login screen show on external monitor without closing Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, login-screen

I have a 2019 Macbook Pro 16". I am trying to get the login screen to show on an external monitor but I do not want to close the MBP.

Once I log-in then the external monitor is primary but I want it to be primary before login, such that the login screen is on it.